# how to align checkboxes to the left of a table in html

Tags: html

I have a table representing data in a database and I'd like there to be checkboxes to the left so that the user can do operations on the selected items (ie delete, modify).  My question is, how can I align the checkboxes to be to the left of the table?

```
<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <th>A bunch of headers</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A row of items</td>

    </tr>
    A lot more rows
</table>
```

Pretty straitforward, I have no idea how to proceed with checkboxes, I tried to put a form around the table but that didn't work.

Comment: Put them **in** the table, then use css to skip borders on the first column.

Comment: Invisible checkboxes!

Comment: @avorum [Here is **an alternative**](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/6ryXE/3/), not using checkboxes at all but using `data-id` attribute on `tr` elements instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a column that contains checkboxes only. Using `td` elements, they will be left-aligned by default.

However, checkboxes should be used to provide a control for selecting or not selecting some parameters, not for triggering actions. Consider using e.g. `button` elements for actions.

Comment: That was my intent, this structure for handling data in a webpage is pretty standard.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS to align them.

margin-left:100px;
float:left;

Answer (score 0):

You could just create an "actions" column which you insert as the first column in your table that contains the checkboxes. That way all checkboxes are kept separate from the contents which makes formatting and manipulation via javascript easier.

Alternatively if you must use a form for each row you could do something like:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" /><span>Data...</span></td>
```

... but if you go the second route you loose the power of tables** & may as well go for a div only solution.

** for displaying tabular data; before someone shoots me down for table vs div for layouts.